# Kafka Stream APis join between Kstream and Ktable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application having kstream reading from one topic multiple partition while ktable reading from another topic multiple partition. So both Kstream & Ktable will refer to same partition in two different topic or any partion in two different topic

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, they have to be co-partitioned (the same number of partitions). Kafka Streams will check it out or throw an exception at startup.

Secondly, you should make sure that producers send records of the same key to the same partitions across these input topics (of a `KStream` and a `KTable`) so the consumer (the Kafka Streams application that uses `join` operator) will ever see any match and `join` succeeds.